# Why can't builtins become bound methods?

Tags: python, class

```
class Something: pass
f=lambda : True
```

Now, if I do

```
Something.open=f
g=Something()
g.open()
```

I get an error that `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` and `g.open` is a `<bound method <lambda> of <__main__.Something object at 0xffff80253400>>`. This means that the `self` object as passed to open.

However, if I do

```
Something.open=open
g=Something()
g.open()
```

I just get an error that `TypeError: open() missing required argument 'file' (pos 1)`, and `g.open` is just `<built-in function open>`, as presumably no arguments are given to `open`.

Why is there a difference?

Follow up: Can I get `f` to act like a built-in function (aka, get no `self` object passed to it)?

Comment: You'll want to read about the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). In short, `f.__get__` is defined, but `open.__get__` is not.

Comment: How would I undefine it (can I do that?)

Comment: Also good to read ["Instance methods" in the Data Model manual chapter](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/datamodel.html#index-35), which I think addresses all these questions. In particular, with respect to builtins, "this transformation [to instance method] only happens for user-defined functions; other callable objects (and all non-callable objects) are retrieved without transformation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you would want to do this, but you can do:

```
class Something:
    pass
f=lambda : True
Something.open=staticmethod(f)
g=Something()
print(g.open())
```

Comment: `staticmethod` is basically just a type whose `__get__` method always returns the underlying function, whether it is accessed via the class or an instance.